# How to auto start service in android?

Tags: android

At Android application, it always extends Activity and the entry is onCreate. So it seems that user has to select application and click to luanch it.(if it is wrong,please advise me. sorry)

So, how to implent a service running on background without user clicking to start application?

Comment: There are several possibilities, but without more details on what you are trying to achieve, it is impossible to say which approach is best.

Comment: Basically There will be an application which will act as like a service. And when I install the applications apk on the emulator/device then the service will start running and that means the whole application is a service. The service will be able to take external request etc.

Comment: You can't start the service automatically after an installation, but you can listen to various broadcasts to start the service.

Answer (score 10):

Use an IntentReceiver to receive the BOOT_COMPLETED_ACTION.

Then in the IntentReceiver, you can call startService().

Comment: Please do not write everlasting services: http://www.androidguys.com/2009/09/09/diamonds-are-forever-services-are-not/ http://www.androidguys.com/2010/03/29/code-pollution-background-control/

Answer (score 5):

> And when I install the applications apk on the emulator/device then the service will start running

That is not possible. Android does not allow applications of any form to run immediately upon installation.